# Error textView on a xml

Tags: android-studio, textview

El `textView` siguiente con texto largo no sé porque pero me quita el espaciado entre líneas pero solo a partir de la se segunda línea, la primera línea no tiene ese error pero sí con la segunda y tercera.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPathBold"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:text="Praesent pretium nulla sit amet mollis consectetur. Aenean sed felis in ante dictum facilisis. Etiam suscipit lorem sed nisl interdum, ac vulputate tortor tempor."
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

La primera imagen es la visualización del layout donde se ve bien, mientras que la segunda imagen es como se visualiza en el móvil.

[image: Imagen del layout]

[image: Imagen del móvil]

Comment: Buenas @user35655, estás en la versión española de Stackoverflow tienes que traducir tu mensaje al Español para poder ayudarte.
Translate your message, please.

Comment: No me di cuenta que estaba en stackoverflow español ahroa lo traduzco, merci

Comment: Ca va,  No entiendo tu pregunta, tienes una imagen?

Comment: @Jorgesys añadidas las imágenes